# Why does the loss of the LSTM model rise up over several epochs?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I set up a simple LSTM model for regression, which is a many to many model. The loss of model declined at the start while it rose up over several epochs. Where am I wrong?

I'have run the model for a epoch number ranging from 200 to 600 on 8 CPU cores, but the results remain same.

Here is my code.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_steps))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I expect the loss would reduce gradually with little fluctuation.

However I saw the result as follows

```
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 281us/step - loss: 6595.8919
Epoch 63/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 289us/step - loss: 6557.3760
Epoch 64/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 280us/step - loss: 6947.0848
Epoch 65/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 282us/step - loss: 6439.9647
Epoch 66/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 277us/step - loss: 6583.3354
Epoch 67/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 278us/step - loss: 6724.0296
Epoch 68/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 279us/step - loss: 6457.0547
Epoch 69/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 278us/step - loss: 6371.6533
Epoch 70/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 279us/step - loss: 6644.9585
Epoch 71/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 277us/step - loss: 6340.0420
Epoch 72/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 279us/step - loss: 9484.5966
Epoch 73/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 277us/step - loss: 10975.8083
Epoch 74/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 275us/step - loss: 10174.8291
Epoch 75/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 282us/step - loss: 9863.0310
Epoch 76/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 278us/step - loss: 9882.6081
Epoch 77/200
7143/7143 [==============================] - 2s 280us/step - loss: 9398.1880
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The learning rate that you are using can be too big for the optimization after 71st epoch. Reason for this is the learning rate can be relatively larger when compared to the error at a later number of epochs than the error at the beginning.

**You can use a smaller learning rate or you can reduce the lr monotonically as a solution for this.**

Good luck :-)